# How to limit the launch of programs that do not have a digital signature?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, operating-system, policy

I have virtual machine with Windows Server 12 r2. It is necessary to limit the launch of programs without a digital signature. Heard about SRP, tried to use, did not work, I do not understand what exactly is needed. I ask for help.

Aim: There are two sets of files - signed / unsigned. It is necessary to check that the OS blocks unsigned files and verify that the signed files are working. Break the digital signature and check the files as the OS responds.

How to do it? Desirable instruction or link!

Comment: This appears to be off topic for SO, try on Server Fault instead - it's probably a better fit for this type of question.

Comment: @fredrik Why then came up with a signature, if they can not be manipulated? I just want the built-in Windows tools to limit the execution of unsigned code.